# changing JTextField formatting

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield, jtextarea

I want to change the format of this JTextField especially the font size and color.

here is the code :

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
JTextArea msgArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the color with by setting a [`Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) color.

```
Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15);

textField.setFont(f);
textField.setForeground(Color.RED);

msgArea.setFont(f);
msgArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: what's the needed librarey?

Comment: @user210939 `import java.awt.Font;` keep an offline api with you